# Interchange upper- and lower-level decision variables in bi-level programming

Tags: optimization, bilevel-optimization

Consider a general bi-level programming as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \min_{x\in X,y\in Y}&~F(x,y) \\
           s.t.&~ G(x,y) \leq 0, \\
               &~ y\in \arg\min_{z\in Y}\{f(x,z): g(x,z)\leq0\}
\end{align*}

Suppose the upper- and lower-level variables are swapped, and we obtain
\begin{align*}
    \min_{x\in X,y\in Y}&~F(x,y) \\
           s.t.&~ G(x,y) \leq 0, \\
               &~ x\in \arg\min_{z\in X}\{f(z,y): g(z,y)\leq0\}
\end{align*}

I understand that swapping upper- and lower-level variables lead to two problems that are not equivalent in general. But I wonder whether they can be equivalent in special conditions. I appreciate much if relevant materials are provided.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A very special case: If both $X$ and $Y$ are 1-element sets and both points satisfy all of the constraints, then the problems are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a very interesting case, but assume the following two things. First, $$g(x,y)\le 0 \implies G(x,y) \le 0 \quad \forall x\in X;\forall y\in Y.$$ Second, $F$ "tracks" $f$ in the sense that $$f(x,y) < f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})\implies F(x,y) < F(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})\quad \forall x,\tilde{x}\in X; \forall y,\tilde{y}\in Y.$$

Now suppose that $(x^*, y^*)$ is the optimal solution to your first problem and $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ is the optimal solution to your second problem, and suppose the objective functions differ. Without loss of generality, assume $F(x^*,y^*) < F(\hat{x},\hat{y}).$ Then it must be that $(x^*,y^*)$ is not feasible in the second problem. Since we know from the first problem that $G(x^*,y^*) \le 0$ and $g(x^*,y^*) \le 0,$ it must be that $$\tilde{x} = \arg\min_{z\in X} \lbrace f(z,y^*) : g(z,y^*) \le 0\rbrace \neq x^*,$$ and more specifically $$f(\tilde{x},y^*) < f(x^*,y^*).$$ Also note that $$g(\tilde{x},y^*) \le 0.$$

Now let $$\tilde{y} = \arg\min_{y\in Y} \lbrace f(\tilde{x}, y) : g(\tilde{x}, y) \le 0\rbrace$$ and observe that $$f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) \le f(\tilde{x},y^*) < f(x^*,y^*).$$Since $$g(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) \le 0 \implies G(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) \le 0,$$ $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ satisfies the constraints of the first problem. Using the "tracking" assumption, $$f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) < f(x^*,y^*)\implies F(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) < F(x^*,y^*),$$ contradicting optimality of $(x^*,y^*)$ in the first problem.

So the two assumptions I listed are sufficient to ensure that the two problems have the same optimal objective value.